# extract image of cell from pdf table PYTHON

Tags: python, json, opencv, neural-network, computer-vision

I need to recognize written text in a table and parse it in json. I do it using python. I don't really understand how to extract photos of text from a table that is in pdf format. Because the usual table recognizer is not suitable, since written text is not recognized there. Accordingly, I need to somehow cut the cells from the table, how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract tables and their cells you probably need a table extractor like this; [1](https://analyticsindiamag.com/how-to-use-opencv-to-extract-information-from-table-images/)

Then after extracting the table and its cells with their coordinates, you are allowed to pick those pixels. For example; img[x1:x2,y1:y2]

After obtaining the cell's pixels, you can use the Tesseract OCR engine to understand the texts written in image pixels.

These are the general steps that you need to follow, I can help you more if you precise your question more.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! the fact is that my table may have empty cells. And the information in it is written in block letters. do you know another way?

Comment: Hımm, I'm not sure Tesseract has this font in its pre-trained version. First of all it doesn't matter your cell is empty or not - means there is text or not- your OCR engine should determine it with your rules. Block letters may not have included in Tesseract's training stage. Then you may fine-tune Tesseract with your specific font and size; "https://github.com/dshea89/tesseract-retraining-pipeline". Or you may want to use other options which is not so popular but very accurate option is "EasyOCR --> https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR". You have again re-train option in this OCR engine .

Answer (score 0):

PDF format has not 'table' and 'cell'.
Covert PDF into PNG format or other raster format and use OCR as say BlackCode.